# Plotly gauge: changing the order of gauge segments

Tags: plotly

See fiddle.  I'm trying to 'flip' this gauge so that the first segment is the 80% one, and the second is the 20% one (by 'first' segment, I mean the one starting at 9 o'clock).  However no matter what order I put the values in the values array, plotly always appears to first sort the values and draw the smallest segment first.  (Note: the '50' value draws an invisible 180-degree white section at the bottom half of the gauge.  That is how Plotly's examples work.)

Anyone able to assist with this?  Thanks!

```
values: [40, 10, 50] // re-arranging the 40 and 10 makes no difference in how the wedges are plotted
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0L6kv7L0/1/

Comment: I think I found a possible solution in the API, which is to add a 'sort: false'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plotly's gauge charts are just deformed pie charts.

You would need to specify the direction in order to enforce the correct orientation.

```
direction: "clockwise"
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/331wpjLk/) for an update of your fiddle and two examples below.

```js
var data = [{
  values: [40, 10, 50],
  marker: {
    colors: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)', 'rgba(110, 154, 22, .5)',
      'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    ]
  },
  text: ['80%', '20%', "I'm just a white piece of pie"],
  textinfo: 'text',
  textposition: 'inside',
  type: 'pie',
  rotation: 90,
  direction: "clockwise"
}];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv1', data);

data = [{
  values: [10, 40, 50],
  marker: {
    colors: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)', 'rgba(110, 154, 22, .5)',
      'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
    ]
  },
  text: ['20%', '80%', "I'm just a white piece of pie"],
  textinfo: 'text',
  textposition: 'inside',
  type: 'pie',
  rotation: 90,
  direction: "counterclockwise"
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv2', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv1" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
</div>
<div id="myDiv2" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;">
</div>
```